# Scroll position restoring rule when reload in web browsers

Tags: javascript, html

In the case of websites that handle data asynchronously, when refresh the browser, in some cases the scroll position is restored and in some cases not.

e.g.) When reload after scrolling down ...

- https://www.bitbox.me -> position restored
- https://scan.link.network/0x3001004/block -> position not restored

My conclusion base on debug with chrome inspector is below.

If the web page is scrollable status before the `window.onload` event emitted, the browser tries to restore scroll position to previous scroll position. In other words, https://www.bitbox.me API response is completed before `window.onload`.

This is only my guess. So I searched the documentation how scroll position restore but failed. Does anyone know more about scroll position recovery criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers support scroll-anchoring. You can read more about it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring

and see which browsers support it here
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-overflow-anchor

I just built out a feature that needed exact control of scroll position. To get back to a browser-agnostic state, just add `overflow-anchor: none;` to the css of the scrollable element.

Comment: Specifically, look at Suppression Triggers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring#Suppression_triggers

Comment: You're a life saver! [Been trying to fix this for almost a year.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70537461)