# Chromium / Chrome page vertical scrolling upwards on soft or hard reload

Tags: css, google-chrome

When soft or hard reloading a page, all newer Chromium based browsers on both Win and Mac perform a slight **vertical scroll upwards between 2-15px**.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>heading</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum.....</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum.....</p>
        <!-- repeat until page scrolls -->
    </body>
 </html>
```

Removing `line-height` fixed the scrolling on reload in some cases. Removing margins on `h1` elements also fixed the scrolling on reload.

Browsers confirmed bugged:

- w11 edge: 96.0.1054.62
- w81 chromium: 96.0.4664.45
- mac chrome: 96.0.4664.110
- w10 chrome: 96.0.4664.110
- w10 edge: 96.0.1054.62
- w10 opera: [latest]

**EDIT**

You can also go to any long scrolling wikipedia page and reproduce. Or any website, for that matter.

**EDIT 2**

Can confirm Firefox suffers the same, although much less frequently and not on subsequent reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the [*scroll anchoring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring) implementation in modern Chromium browsers.

The fix is `body { overflow-anchor: none; }` to opt out of scroll anchoring.

Answer (score 0):

This fix produces the same behavior on the dev.mozilla/CSS_Grid page linked above. You could get away with bringing the `setTimeout` to as low as 25, but lower than that and the rescroll won't happen.

```
/**
 * Maybe scroll on reload
 *
 * All Chromium browsers >= 96.0.1054.62 have a reload/rescroll bug that scrolls
 * the window by 1-2 pixels per reload
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageName = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop(); // string(6) "README"

    $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem(pageName + "_scroll_pos", document.documentElement.scrollTop); // README_scroll_pos = 225
    });
    if (window.performance.navigation.type) { // Run if there is a reload or navigation event; reload = 1, navigation = 2
        setTimeout(function() {
            var yPos = sessionStorage.getItem(pageName + "_scroll_pos");

            if (yPos && yPos != document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
                //console.log("We are scrolling to yPos: " + yPos + " because document.documentElement.scrollTop is now: " + document.documentElement.scrollTop);
                $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem(pageName + "_scroll_pos"));

                //console.log("We are deleting " + pageName + "_scroll_pos");
                sessionStorage.removeItem(pageName + "_scroll_pos");
            }
            //else {
            //    console.log("We are NOT scrolling to yPos: " + yPos + " because document.documentElement.scrollTop is already: " + document.documentElement.scrollTop);
            //    console.log("We are NOT deleting " + pageName + "_scroll_pos");
            //}
            //console.log(sessionStorage);
        }, 100);
    }
});
```